# How to refresh a page on dropdownlist value change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a common layout page for views. This layout page contains a dropdown list, which shows the list of available dates. What I want is to reload this page having changed the data param only. The controller, action and any other params should be somehow taken from the current request context.

If I wanted to do it manually on every view, I'd say it would be equal to

```
@Html.ActionLink(
     "",                                        
     "I need to have current action name here", 
     new { date = "The Value of the chosen SelectListItem" });
```

How can I achieve this? Or is there any different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about current action is available in `RequestContext`, you could access it directly:

```
@Url.Action(ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"], 
         new { date = "The Value of the chosen SelectListItem" });
```

In your case I would add the url to option data attribute and then work with it with jQuery:

```
$('select#yourid').change(function() {
    document.location.href = $(this).find('option:selected').data('url'));
});​
```

How to fetch data attribute on dropdownlist change can be seen in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NpzUE/).

Comment: Sorry, but how to make the browser to go to this link on the dropdownlist values change?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you need help with the rendering part, let me know. I don't have Visual Studio at hand at the moment..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do appreciate your help

Answer (score -2):

Html:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="list" size="1"> 
   <option value="1">Option 1</option> 
   <option value="2">Option 2</option> 
</select> 
<span id="tag"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
//cache the select and span elements  var mySelect =
 document.getElementById("mySelect"), 
 tag = document.getElementById("tag");    //when it changes  
 mySelect.onchange = function() { 
 //change the tag innerHTML checking the selected value of the select 
 tag.innerHTML = mySelect.value === "1" ? "some text" : "some other text";  }
```

That was an example. If you wan to load another page- call another JS function, or ajax control